# Logical Quantifiers

Tags: analysis, logic, quantifiers

I am wondering if there is a reference or book that clearly translates all English forms of logical quantifiers to mathematical quantifiers.

For example, when we say for any element $ x \in S$, is this equivalent to saying $\forall x \in S$? And what is implied when quantifiers are left out? For example, $s$ and $t$ are elements of $S$? Is this equivalent to $\forall s,t \in S$?

Sincerely,
Frank

Comment: There's a fundamental difficulty that English is not mathematics!  Many writers have noted that "any" may be correctly used in English sentences with ambiguity as to whether universal or existential quantification is intended.  E.g. "Does any book clearly translate English forms of logical quantifiers to mathematical quantifiers?" might be understood either as "does *some* book do this" or as "does *every* book do this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a reference or book that clearly translates all English forms of logical quantifiers to mathematical quantifiers.

Any good introductory logic text should help you out here. I confess a sneaking admiration for P*t*r Sm*th's *Introduction to Formal Logic* which, I'm told, students find particularly helpful on such  matters of translation. But freely available on line, and (probably!) just as good, is Paul Teller's *A Modern Logic Primer*: you want the opening chapters of Vol. 2. See http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu

> For example, when we say for any element x∈S, is this equivalent to saying ∀x∈S? And what is implied when quantifiers are left out? For example, s and t are elements of S? Is this equivalent to ∀s,t∈S?

When we say "for any element $x \in S$, $Px$", then yes, this is usually just the same as claiming $(\forall x \in S)Px$. But when we drop the quantifier, and just assume $s$ be an element of $S$ (or say "let $s$ be an element of $S$" or the like) we are not yet quantifying. The context typically is one where we are selecting a single arbitrary element, with a view to proving e.g. that it has some property $P$, so we can then -- because $s$ is arbitrary, i.e. we make no special assumptions about it -- we go on to generalize and *infer* $(\forall x \in S)Px$.

Comment: Does $\forall s,t \in S$ include choices for $s$ and $t$ that are equivalent? For example, consider a set $S = \{ a, b, c \}$, and the statement $\forall s,t \in S, \exists s,t$ such that $s=t$. Is the statement true? Also, of what "thing" is this a property? I see that the statement is a predicate and is either true or false, but it is not clear whether we consider such a statement to be a property of $S$ or just elements $s,t \in S$ where $s = t$.

Comment: @baffld - *(i)* Yes; when we write $\forall s,t \in S$, $s$ and $t$ can be the same object of $S$. *(ii)* This formula is not a good example; when you write $\exists s,t (s = t)$, this a correct formula. But in this formula $s$ and $t$ are no more free; so, what are you meaning with the "added" quantifier $\forall s,t$ upfront? Due to the fact that in $\exists s,t (s = t)$ there are no free vars, the added quantifier has no effect. *(iii)* When you write $\forall x P(x)$, you are predicating $P$ of the objects of the "domain" on which the individual variables $s$ and $t$ are "ranging".

Answer (score 0):

$x \in S$ is not the same as $\forall x \in S$.

$\in$ means "is an element of," so $x \in S$ simply denotes the membership of $x$ to $S$, while $\forall x \in S$, meaning "for all x that is an element of $S$" must modify an action like "Let $f(x)=x^2, \forall x \in S$." The two statements are not logically equivalent in many cases. For instance, you cannot replace: "Let $x \in S$" with "Let "$\forall x \in S$."

But if you state that something happens for $x \in S$, then it is implied that you mean $\forall x \in S$. e.g., "Let $f(x)=x^2, \forall x \in S$" is the same as "Let $f(x)=x^2, x \in S$".

For a comprehensive list, try these: http://www.philosophy-index.com/logic/symbolic/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

Comment: Thanks Mathster. That is very helpful.